# EmberJS - Not able to get property from "service' from Component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my ember application, I am trying to retrieve the data from service to component, but I am getting an error as :

`TypeError: this.start.toggleProperty is not a function` - But i have a property there is service.

Here is my component js :

import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    start: Ember.inject.service( ),
    message: null,
    actions: {
        pressMe() {
            this.start.toggleProperty('isOn'); //throws error
            // this.set('message',this.start.importantInfo( ));
            // Ember.log(this.start.isOn);
            console.log( "start is", this.start.isOn ); //undefined!?
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my service js :

import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
    isOn: false,
    importantInfo( ){
        return "Important Info is " + this.get('isOn');
    }
});
```

Do I missed something? any one suggest me the correct way please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that `import ...` not part of the code? If it is, please format it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is,

```
this.get('start').toggleProperty('isOn')
```

Reason is,

> Injected properties are lazy loaded; meaning the service will not be
>   instantiated until the property is explicitly called. Therefore you
>   need to access services in your component using the get function
>   otherwise you might get an undefined.

Reference:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/applications/services/#toc_accessing-services